# Talend String handling convert "0.12900-" string to -0.12900 in float

Tags: talend

Need help with the below conversion in Talend:

"0.12900-"  string to -0.12900 in float via Tmap expression.

I am not well versed with Java hence the difficulty.

Comment: Is every entry negative?

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this : 
`row1.column.contains("-")?Float.parseFloat( "-"+ StringHandling.LEFT(row1.column,row1.column.length()-1)):Float.parseFloat(row1.column)`

Float.parseFloat allows you to convert a string to a float type.

StringHandling.LEFT gets the first characters of a string, here the total length-1.

Ternary operator controls if your string contains "-", otherwise you just have to parse the "-" symbol

Comment: This only works when *every* row should have a negative value.